# What do "heating degree day" prices actually measure?

Tags: options, futures, derivatives

The futures for Dallas Heating Degree days for July 2022 are [trading around 6.83](https://futures.tradingcharts.com/futures/quotes/H5.html?cbase=H5)
But Dallas is hot in July and does not typically get [any heating degree days](https://www.climate-zone.com/climate/united-states/texas/dallas-fort-worth/)
So, what does the 6.83 for July 2022 correspond to?

Comment: I am pretty sure these quotes refer to Cooling Degree Days. Airconditioning is a must in Dallas in July.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure these futures are trading? There is no data on BBG - or the [CME](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/weather/temperature/us-monthly-weather-heating.quotes.html).

I have no experience with these products, but I am almost certain that there are no quotes (and hence no trading) for July weather futures for Dallas at the CME.

I don't think it's CDD either (should be a lot higher - around 480 according to the second link in the question, which seems reasonable) but just bad data. According to the [CME](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/weather/temperature/us-monthly-weather-heating.contractSpecs.options.html), the contract months for HDD are Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar plus Oct and Apr only.

CME's official [WEATHER Products code sheet](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/weather/files/Weather_Code_Sheet.pdf) also shows no such thing as a H5 N22 (Dallas June 22 future) as your link claims.

Comment: How exactly would I trade weather futures? Can I do it through ICE (Intercontinental Exchange)?

Comment: [The ICE](https://www.theice.com/products/) does not offer weather. You may have misread my answer, but the CME does offer weather futures, just not July contracts like you asked. Besides, I assume you are a retail investor, in which case you would need to find a broker who offers them (who offers trading in CME weather futures). No idea if there are any.